# Trouble creating DropdownListFor with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a select list on my form. I am using Razors Html.DropDownListFor, but I am uncertain how to properly populate my DropDownList with the appropriate values from my model.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Options.Count(); j++)
   {
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Questions[i].Options[j].IsSelected, ????)
   }
}
```

**MODELS:**

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string QuestionType { get; set; }

    public string SubType { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }    
}

public class QuestionOptionViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public int Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below solution. I slightly changed your models -

```
public class QuestionMainModel
{
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    public int Selected { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionOptionViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }        
}
```

The controller action which populates the view -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        QuestionMainModel model = new QuestionMainModel();

        List<QuestionOptionViewModel> options = new List<QuestionOptionViewModel>();
        options.Add(new QuestionOptionViewModel(){ Id = 1, Text = "Ans1", Value = "1"});
        options.Add(new QuestionOptionViewModel(){ Id = 2, Text = "Ans2", Value = "2"});
        options.Add(new QuestionOptionViewModel(){ Id = 3, Text = "Ans3", Value = "3"});

        model.Questions = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
        model.Questions.Add(new QuestionViewModel() { Id = 1, Text = "Question1", Options = options });

        return View(model);
    }
```

The view which is being displayed is as follows -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.QuestionMainModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "sample", FormMethod.Post))
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Questions[i].Text, Model.Questions[i].Text)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Questions[i].Selected, new SelectList(Model.Questions[i].Options, "Value", "Text"), "Select an option")
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
}
```

And when you click submit button, it will hit below controller action -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(QuestionMainModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

And the selected answer would be as follows -

[image]

**NOTE:** If you want to post all the options and Question Text, then use HiddenFields, just like I did for Is.

Comment: I didn't really need to make any considerable edits to my model. I really took what you had for DropDownListFor and pretty much it works. @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Questions[i].Selected, new SelectList(Model.Questions[i].Options, "Id", "Text"),new {@class = "form-control"})

Comment: @allencoded, hopefully yes, give a try. But you might need to change Razor code a bit.

Comment: Ah it did not. Guess I may have to open another question for that

Comment: @allencoded, probably yes, you might need to open one more question. I will keep an eye on your new question too :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => 
       m.Questions[i].Id,
       new SelectList(
           m.Questions[i].Options, 
           "Text",
           "Value",
           m.Questions[i].Options.SingleOrDefault(x = > x.IsChecked).Value))
}
```

But keep in mind that you should have only one Option that has IsChecked flag set to true. Otherwise you will receive an error.

Comment: Doing this returns an error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object